# Como repetir dados iguais usando data.map

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Estou usando a biblioteca d3.js e queria que, ao ler dados iguais, não sobrescrevesse na hora de desenhar as escalas.

Segue o trecho de código que faz isso e um exemplo do meu arquivo .json:

```
const months = data.map(function(d) {
            //console.log(d.month);
            return d.month;
        });
        //console.log(months);
```

No caso a constante `months` está recebendo um array.

```
const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
            .rangeRound([0, w])
            .domain(months);
```

Porém na hora que uso a função `d3.ScaleBand()` ele sobrescreve os dados que estão iguais, mas eu queria que não fizesse isso.

```
svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + marginLeft + ',' + marginRight +')')
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
```

arquivo .json:

```
[
  {"month": "January", "days": 30},
  {"month": "February", "days": 28},
  {"month": "March", "days": 31},
  {"month": "April", "days": 30},
  {"month": "May", "days": 15},
  {"month": "June", "days": 30},
  {"month": "July", "days": 22},
  {"month": "August", "days": 11},
  {"month": "September", "days": 30},
  {"month": "October", "days": 8},
  {"month": "November", "days": 30},
  {"month": "December", "days": 25},
  {"month": "September", "days": 3},
  {"month": "October", "days": 18}
]
```

Nesse caso repeti os meses "September" e "October" no final, porém na hora de desenhar as escalas, ele desenha em cima dos já existentes.